# ID Not Submitting To Query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I appreciate your responses in advance.

I have several pages of orders that I am dealing with, however I am sure fixing one will provide me with enough knowledge to fix the others. In this case, I will show you the `daytasks.php` section. Basically, I can make function changes to the first line, but the second, third, etc. lines cannot be modified. Using the function buttons does nothing for those lines. `daytasks.php` calls upon `fetchdaytasks.php` to get the information based on date, which calls upon `./functions/additions.js` to perform the Javascript, which calls upon  the functions corresponding script to perform the action requested.

e.g. I have two orders, each in their own separate `<tr>`, I can modify the first row, which is ID #`28` with any of the functions, but the second row, ID #`35` I cannot modify, it will simply not make any changes.

Portion of `daytasks.php`

```
<div class="form-group">  
                <br />
                <center>
                     <div class="input-group"> 
                        <input type="date" id="search_text" name="search_text" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="result"></div>  
                </center>
</div>
```

Portion of `fetchdaytasks.php`

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
 {  
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
     {
         $id=$row['id'];
         $orderdate=$row['date'];
         $order=$row['order'];
         $status=$row['status'];
 echo "
                <td><center>$id</center></td>
                <td><center>$orderdate</center></td>
                <td><center>$order</center></td>
                <td><center>$status</center></td>
                <form>
                <td><center><button type='button' name='btn_ship' id='btn_ship' class='btn btn-xs btn-success' data-id='$id'>SHIP</button> <button type='button' name='btn_unship' id='btn_unship' class='btn btn-xs btn-danger btn_delete'>UNSHIP</button> <button type='button' name='btn_bo' id='btn_bo' class='btn btn-xs btn-danger btn_delete'>BACKORDER</button> <button type='button' name='btn_fbo' id='btn_fbo' class='btn btn-xs btn-danger btn_delete'>FBO</button><br />
            <button type='button' name='btn_cancel' id='btn_cancel' class='btn btn-xs btn-danger btn_delete'>CANCEL</button> <button type='button' name='btn_return' id='btn_return' class='btn btn-xs btn-danger btn_delete'>RETURN</button> <button type='button' name='btn_dam' id='btn_dam' class='btn btn-xs btn-danger btn_delete'>DAMAGED</button> <button type='button' name='btn_lost' id='btn_lost' class='btn btn-xs btn-danger btn_delete'>LOST</button></td>
            </form>
            </tr>
            ";
     }
 }
 else
 {
     echo "No Orders For This Date";
 }
```

Portion of `additions.js`

```
    $("#btn_ship").click(function(){
var changeid = $( this ).data('id');    
 var myData={"changeid":changeid};
 $.ajax({
    url : "./functions/shiporder.php",
    type: "POST",
    data : myData,
    success: function(data,status,xhr)
     {
        $("#status_text").html(data);
        $('#changeid').val();
     }
}); 
});

$("#btn_fbo").click(function(){
 var changeid = $('#changeid').val();       
 var myData={"changeid":changeid};
 $.ajax({
    url : "./functions/fboorder.php",
    type: "POST",
    data : myData,
    success: function(data,status,xhr)
     {
        $("#status_text").html(data);
        $('#changeid').val();
     }
}); 
});
```

`./functions/fboorder.php`

```
<?php  
include_once('/home/brandina/public_html/eldis/config/config.php');
 $changeid = $_POST['changeid'];
 if(mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE `orders` SET `status`='FBO' WHERE `id`='$changeid'"))
 ?>
```

`./functions/shiporder.php`

```
<?php  
include_once('/home/brandina/public_html/eldis/config/config.php');
 $changeid = $_POST['changeid'];
 if(mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE `orders` SET `status`='SHIP' WHERE `id`='$changeid'"))
 ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are looping in fetchdaytasks, this line will be repeated:
`<input type='hidden' id='changeid' name='changeid' value='$id' />`

That means you will have multiple elements with an "id" of 'changeid'. In your JS you have `var changeid = $('#changeid').val();`
This does not know which #changeid you are talking about.

So I would get rid of the hidden input and work with "data-XXX" and put that on the buttons or on the form.

So `<button type='button' name='btn_ship' id='btn_ship' class='btn btn-xs btn-success' data-id='$id'>SHIP</button>` or `<form data-id='$id'>`

And then get the id in the JS like:
`var changeid = $( this ).data( 'id );` in case you do it on the button.

Comment: Almost correct. If you have multiple html elements with the same id, then getElementById() returns one of the elements. It is indeterminate which one (usually the first one from the top).

Comment: I appreciate both of your comments. Not to ask you to build the JS code for me, but  could you help me modify the JS script so I can work with the data id you provided? I think this option would work, and I had tried it based on previous scripts I had on hand, but I was unsuccessful, most likely as I was not doing it right.

Comment: @Omnisite - I appreciate your edit. I added the `data-id='$id'` to my button and used the suggested `var changeid = $( this ).data( 'id );` in place of the original `var` in my JS - and now it is unable to modify any of the lines. Thoughts?

Comment: @Shadow do you have any suggestions to replicate this issue? I made suggested changes by however it now performs the same function as before, only working with the top row.

Comment: Your js onclick event handlers are still tied to duplicated id attribues. Solution is pretty simple: do not tie your event handlers to id, tie them to class.

Comment: @BrandinArsenault Sorry, typo. Did you do `$( this ).data( 'id );` or `$( this ).data( 'id' );` ?

Comment: @Omnisite I noticed that error so I corrected it - it resulted in the query performing the same action as before, only the top row.